# How to access node from azure machine learning compute?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When submitting an aml compute job, I want to access the nodes where the compute happens for debugging purposes. The portal gives me the IP address, the port and the nodeID, but no password seems to exist within the portal.

How am I supposed to connect to the machine?

I am running on NC6 machines for a single node training. I have already tried to run the command given through the portal, but the node is (hopefully so) protected by a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to log in to the nodes of an AML Compute cluster, you have to provide a username and password and ssh key (ssh key is optional), **when you create the cluster**. You can only do that at creation time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting up your cluster, you can define a username/password/ssh key that can be used to login to the cluster. If you did not define these at the time of creation, you would need to recreate the cluster unfortunately.

We are working on better documenting this, and also update our messaging a bit.